# Maximum of trinomial coefficient

Tags: multinomial-coefficients

I read a proof about the simple random walk in 3 dimensions and couldn't understand the following statement:
$$\frac{n!}{k!j!(n-k-j)!}$$ has the maximum when $\ k, j $ and $\ n-k-j$ are as close to $\frac{n}{3}$ as possible.

Does anyone show me a proof for this?

Comment: This may help.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008249/maximizing-the-trinomial-coefficient

Comment: I assume the proof follows the same pattern as the one showing that the maximum binomial coefficient is the [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient).

Comment: Thanks. I have read this argument, but I want to see a rigorous proof. I think of Stirling formula for each factorial term, but cannot derive the result from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is equivalent to show how to minimize $a!b!c!$ with $a+b+c=n$. Suppose $a-b>1$, then replace $a,b$ by $a-1,b+1$ we will get a smaller product as $(a-1)b(b+1)<(a-1)ab$. By the symmetry of $a,b,c$, the result follows, since $a,b,c$ are as close to $n/3$ as possible means exactly each pair in $a,b,c$ has no differnce greater than $1$.

Comment: Did you mean to *minimize* $a!b!c!$ with $a+b+c=n$?

Comment: Thanks. I have read this argument, but I want to see a rigorous proof. I think of Stirling formula for each factorial term, but cannot derive the result from that.

Comment: I think my answer is quite rigorous if you could have the ability to understand it...